# Java merge? mix? 2 audio files(mp3) parallely and download it

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg, merge

is there any way to mix 2 audio files parallely and let user download it?

I was trying it by ffmpeg

```
String audioInputPath1 = "sample_audio1.wav";
String audioInputPath2 = "sample_audio2.wav";
String outputFilePath1  = "filePath";
FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("C:\\filePath\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg);
FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("C:\\filePath\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");

FFmpegProbeResult probeResult = ffprobe.probe(audioInputPath1);
FFmpegProbeResult probeResult2 = ffprobe.probe(audioInputPath2);

FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
.overrideOutputFiles(true)
.setInput(audioInputPath2)
.addInput(audioInputPath1)
.addOutput(outputFilePath2)
.setFormat("wav")
.setAudioCodec("libmp3lame")
.setAudioBitRate(256000)
.done();

executor.createJob(builder).run();
```

after i run this code, i get proper .wav file at my outputfilepath, but what i get is just same copy of sample_audio2.wav. no concat, or merged with sample_audio1.wav can i get any help on this problem??

Comment: If what you want is concatenate two wav files, there's a neat program from doing that called "joinwav" from this URL : www.pc-tools.net

Comment: And if you want to compress it to mp3 afterwards, you can use the LAME compressor : https://lame.sourceforge.io/links.php